# How can I create a VCL control with a Published field of type Vcl.ButtonGroup.TButtonGroup

Tags: delphi, properties, vcl

I would like to create a `TSpeedButton` descendant named `TMyDropDownButton` with a `TButtonGroup` field. When I push the `TSpeedButton`, the `TButtonGroup` should appear in the right place (due to some other property values venished here).

This `TButtonGroup` property should be read-only (the program creates it in the `Create()` constructor before the `inherited` constructor is called), and should be published (save the design-time values into the DFM).

But, when I place a `TMyDropDownButton` instance onto a form, the `TButtonGroup` property is unset by default. I can link a dropped `TButtonGroup` when I add a write accessor to the `TButtonGroup` property, but I don`t want this. I want the` TButtonGroup`property to be linked to the`TButtonGroup`instance created in the constructor, and preset by the`Loaded()` method.

How can I do that?

Here is my attempt:

```
unit MyDropDownButton;

interface

uses
    System.Classes
  , Vcl.ButtonGroup
  , Vcl.Buttons
  ;

type
  TMyDropDownButton = class ( TSpeedButton )
    private
      // Fields
      fButtonGroup : TButtonGroup;

    protected
      procedure Loaded; override;

    public
      constructor Create( owner_ : TComponent );
      destructor Destroy; override;

    published
      property buttonGroup : TButtonGroup read fButtonGroup;

  end;


procedure Register;


implementation


procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('myDropDownButton', [TMyDropDownButton]);
end;

procedure TMyDropDownButton.Loaded;
begin
  inherited Loaded;
  // I need some settings here due to venished props inrelevant for the question
end;

constructor TMyDropDownButton.Create( owner_ : TComponent );
begin
  fButtonGroup := TButtonGroup.Create( self );
  inherited Create( owner_ );
  fButtonGroup.Parent := parent;
end;

destructor TMyDropDownButton.Destroy;
begin
//  FreeAndNIL( fButtonGroup );
  inherited Destroy;
end;


end.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TButtonGroup` is a `TComponent` descendant, so in order for your component to use it as a nested property within the Object Inspector, you have to call its `SetSubComponent()` method, eg:

```pascal
constructor TMyDropDownButton.Create( owner_ : TComponent );
begin
  inherited Create( owner_ );
  fButtonGroup := TButtonGroup.Create( Self );
  fButtonGroup.SetSubComponent( True );
  ... 
end;
```

Otherwise, the Object Inspector will expect you to link the property to an external component, as you have already discovered.

Also, you can't set the `TButtonGroup.Parent` property to your component's `Parent` property from inside of your component's constructor, because your component's `Parent` has not been assigned yet at that time.

If you need the `TButtonGroup` to use the same `Parent` that is assigned to your component, you will have to override your component's virtual `SetParent()` method, eg:

```pascal
type
  TMyDropDownButton = class ( TSpeedButton )
    ...
    protected
      ...
      procedure SetParent(AParent: TWinControl); override;
    ...
  end;

procedure TMyDropDownButton.SetParent(AParent: TWinControl); 
begin
  inherited SetParent(AParent);
  fButtonGroup.Parent := AParent;
end;
```